# Android recycler view onItemClick identify the adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have 3 different adapters for 1 Recycler view and I've implemented the OnClick Listener of all 3 in my class :

```
    public class PokemonMovesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements LearnsetRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener,
            TecnicalHiddenMachineRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener,
            EggmoveRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener {

 private LearnsetRecyclerAdapter learnsetRecyclerAdapter;
        private TecnicalHiddenMachineRecyclerAdapter tecnicalHiddenMachineRecyclerAdapter;
        private EggmoveRecyclerAdapter eggmoveRecyclerAdapter;
           
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
           //HERE I NEED TO IDENTIFY WHICH ADAPTER I'VE SUMMONED
        }
    
    }
    
    public void setAdaptersListeners(){
     //Here I instance the adapters and i set the listener...
    }
```

My 3 Adapters have this implemented :

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

   ......

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        ......
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) {
            mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
public Move getItem(int id) {
    return learnsetMoves.get(id);
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

I've tested it and its working , with the debugger I can see which position and the view is summonned in on click , however I don't know WHICH adapters was called , I only get the view and the position :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum AdapterType {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mClickListener != null) {
        view.setTag(AdapterType.First);
        mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    //HERE I NEED TO IDENTIFY WHICH ADAPTER I'VE SUMMONED
    AdapterType adapterType = (AdapterType) view.getTag();
}
```